# Can salad dressing be made with coconut oil?

Tags: salad-dressing, coconut-oil

Can salad dressing be made with coconut oil? Does one need to blend it to homogenize it? Will coagulation of occur afterwards?
<sup>At room temperature, coconut oil is not liquid like vegetable oils.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Coconut oil melts at 76 °F, so simply substitute it for other oils in dressing recipes, place it in the sun to warm it up, and then shake it to homogenize it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it needs to be a warm dressing.

The only warm dressing that I'm aware of is for spinach salad, where you use bacon fat to make the dressing.  See [Alton Brown's Spinach Salad with Warm Bacon Dressing](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/spinach-salad-with-warm-bacon-dressing-recipe-1947599)

I would stick with dark, hearty greens or cabbage, as they'll hold up better to the heat than most lettuces will.

Comment: What do you mean by "warm"? Warmer than room temperature?

Comment: @Geremia : see the recipe that I linked to.  For the dressing, is states  "Transfer the fat to a small saucepan set over low heat and whisk in the red wine vinegar, sugar and Dijon mustard. Season with a small pinch each of kosher salt and black pepper."